# Generate two lists at once

Tags: python

**Background**

The algorithm manipulates financial analytics. There are multiple lists of the same size and they are filtered into other lists for analysis. I am doing the same filtering on different by parallel lists. I could set it up so that a1,b1,c2 occur as a tuple in a list but then the analytics have to stripe the tuples the other way to do analysis (regression of one list against the other, beta, etc.).

**What I want to do**

I want to generate two different lists based on a third list:

```
>>> a = list(range(10))
>>> b = list(range(10,20))
>>> c = list(i & 1 for i in range(10))
>>>
>>> aprime = [a1 for a1, c1 in zip(a,c) if c1 == 0]
>>> bprime = [b1 for b1, c1 in zip(b,c) if c1 == 0]
>>> aprime
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
>>> bprime
[10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
```

It seems there should be a pythonic/functional programming/itertools way to create the two lists and iterate over the three lists only once. Something like:

```
aprime, bprime = [a1, b1 for a1, b1, c1 in zip(a,b,c) if c1 == 0]
```

But of course this generates a syntax error.

**The question**

Is there a pythonic way?

**Micro-optimization shootout**

The ugly but pythonic-to-the-max one-liner edges out the "just use a for-loop" solution and my original code in the ever popular *timeit* cage match:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit("z2(a,b,c)", "n=100;a = list(range(n)); b = list(range(10,10+n)); c = list(i & 1 for i in range(n));\ndef z2(a,b,c):\n\treturn zip(*[(a1,b1) for a1,b1,c1 in zip(a,b,c) if c1==0])\n")
26.977873025761482
>>> timeit.timeit("z2(a,b,c)", "n=100;a = list(range(n)); b = list(range(10,10+n)); c = list(i & 1 for i in range(n));\ndef z2(a,b,c):\n\taprime, bprime = [], [];\n\tfor a1, b1, c1 in zip(a, b, c):\n\t\tif c1 == 0:\n\t\t\taprime.append(a1);  bprime.append(b1);\n\treturn aprime, bprime\n")
32.232914169258947
>>> timeit.timeit("z2(a,b,c)", "n=100;a = list(range(n)); b = list(range(10,10+n)); c = list(i & 1 for i in range(n));\ndef z2(a,b,c):\n\treturn [a1 for a1, c1 in zip(a,c) if c1 == 0], [b1 for b1, c1 in zip(b,c) if c1 == 0]\n")
32.37302275847901
```

Comment: Why are you trying to iterate over lists in parallel?  What's the overall problem you're tying to solve?  It's probably simpler than trying to iterate over multiple parallel lists.

Comment: The algorithm manipulates financial analytics. There are multiple lists of the same size and they are filtered into other lists for analysis. It really is the case that I am doing the same filtering on different by parallel lists. I could set it up so that a1,b1,c2 occur as a tuple in a list but then the analytics have to stripe the tuples the other way to do analysis (regression of one list against the other, beta, etc.).

Comment: I don't get what the problem is with the code you have for creating aprime and bprime.  In what way is it incorrect or unsuitable?

Comment: @S.Lott: Part of it is that there ought to be a better way that succinctly presents the multiple use of one list. Part of it is that I think I can learn better python by asking the question. Part of it is that I think the functional/itertools/pythonic way is likely faster (though not relevant to my circumstances).

Comment: @hughdbrown: I'm not sure that micro-optimizing your use of a single list in this way is "better" python.  Indeed, the ugliness factor says that this is no better than your original -- very clear -- set of statements.

Comment: "ugly but pythonic-to-the-max" -- type `import this` into the python interpreter and read the first line..

Comment: @Y'all: I have more than a few of these lists. I think that emphasizing the common source is worth it and not ugly. I don't honestly understand the animus against this question. Look at recent python questions. See how many are about finding fast micro-optimizations. And the answer I selected reminds me of the code Peter Norvig writes http://www.norvig.com/spell-correct.html or posts on wordaligned.org http://wordaligned.org/tag/python or the MasterMind question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185634/how-to-solve-the-mastermind-guessing-game.

@John Fouhy: 3.0 Import of the day=antigravity

Comment: @hughdbrown:  I see a lot of legacy code as part of replacing it with something maintainable  I have to disagree with "emphasizing the common source is worth it and not ugly."  Simple trumps all other concerns.  Reducing a tiny repetition through zip-unzip isn't really helpful to those who will maintain this code. *All* micro-optimizations are a bad policy.  In the long run, the maintenance (and rewrite) cost make fancy code a liability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might win the ugliest code award, but it works in one line:

```
aprime, bprime = zip(*[(a1,b1) for a1,b1,c1 in zip(a,b,c) if c1==0])
```

Comment: @kaizer.se: what does this comment mean?

Comment: Maybe that zip can be used to unzip if you use an asterisk?
zip(*zip(a,b)) == a,b

Comment: zip--unzip, it feels like it could be a python idiom but in the end I think it is rarely used; a for loop is clearer. By the way, you can use a generator expression instead of list comprehension (I'm not sure it matters here), and then there is itertools.izip if the lists are very long.

Answer (score 4):

Just use a `for` loop:

```
aprime = []
bprime = []
for a1, b1, c1 in zip(a, b, c):
    if c1 == 0:
        aprime.append(a1) 
        bprime.append(b1)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to create multiple lists at a time with list comprehensions--if you only want to iterate once you're going to need to do it some other way--possible with a loop.

You *could* use a list comprehension to create a list of tuples, with the first element belonging to one list, the second to the other. But if you do want them as separate lists, you're going to have to use another operation to split it, anyway.