# Choosing permutations with constraints

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to solve the “Mastermind” guessing game?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185634/how-to-solve-the-mastermind-guessing-game)

I have to choose `k` items out of `n` choices, and my selection needs to be in the correct order (i.e. permutation, not combination). After I make a choice, I receive a hint that tells me how many of my selections were correct, and how many were in the correct order.

For example, if I'm trying to choose `k=4` out of `n=6` items, and the correct ordered set is `5, 3, 1, 2`, then an exchange may go as follows:

```
0,1,2,3
(3, 0) # 3 correct, 0 in the correct position

0,1,2,5
(3, 0)

0,1,5,3
(3, 0)

0,5,2,3
(3,0)

5,1,2,3
(4,1)

5,3,1,2
(4,4)

-> correct order, the game is over
```

The problem is I'm only given a limited number of tries to get the order right, so if `n=6, k=4`, then I only get `t=6` tries, if `n=10,k=5` then `t=5`, and if `n=35,k=6` then `t=18`.

**Where do I start to write an algorithm that solves this?** It almost seems like a constraint solving problem. The hard part seems to be that I only know something for sure if I only change 1 thing at once, but the upper bound on that is way more than the number of tries I get.

Comment: Search for algorithms on Master Mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple strategy for an algorithm is to come up with a next guess that is consistent with all previous hints. This will eventually lead to the right solution, but most likely not in the lowest possible number of guesses.

Comment: here's a simple implementation: http://brainwagon.org/2009/11/22/a-simple-naive-implementation-of-a-mastermind-solver/ i think it can be made faster in this case by making a set of all permutations, and pulling from that. the problem is itertools.permutation() pegs the memory on n=35, k=6 case. i may try something in c.

Answer (score 1):

As I can see, this a variation of mastermind board game http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_(board_game)

Also, you can find more details about the problem in this paper

http://arxiv.org/abs/cs.CC/0512049