# python script for Mastermind solving stops unexpectedly (also gives error after increasing range)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I've tried to adapt one of the given scripts here:

[How to solve the "Mastermind" guessing game?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185634/how-to-solve-the-mastermind-guessing-game)

When i'm trying to get results for:

digits = 4

variables = 10

times_until = 100

...I'm not having any problem. But when i try to increase 'variables' to 12 program stops after progressing a little.

Also i have another issue that if i change 'times_until' to 500 program gives me error like below:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
                File "/Users/ivalaostiapytriel/Dropbox/MastermindSolver.py", line 72, in <module>
                        rungame(hidden_code, strategy_allrand)
                File "/Users/ivalaostiapytriel/Dropbox/MastermindSolver.py", line 58, in rungame
                restart_game()
                File "/Users/ivalaostiapytriel/Dropbox/MastermindSolver.py", line 37, in restart_game
                rungame(hidden_code, strategy_allrand)
                File "/Users/ivalaostiapytriel/Dropbox/MastermindSolver.py", line 58, in rungame
                restart_game()
                ...
                ...
                restart_game()
                File "/Users/ivalaostiapytriel/Dropbox/MastermindSolver.py", line 37, in restart_game
                rungame(hidden_code, strategy_allrand)
                File "/Users/ivalaostiapytriel/Dropbox/MastermindSolver.py", line 50, in rungame
                print ("That's it.  After %d tries, I won." % (i+1,))
                File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/idlelib/PyShell.py", line 1347, in write
                return self.shell.write(s, self.tags)
                RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
                >>>
```

Note that I'm NOT knowledgeable -even slightly- about python. Just had a lecture at back university about it, but not any other experience. Just need to adapt it for a project and retrieve some results from this.

Here is the code I've adapted down below. I would be glad if anyone mention where I am doing wrong to cause these errors.

```
                import random
                #from itertools import izip, imap
                try:
                # Python 2
                from itertools import izip
                from itertools import imap
                except ImportError:
                # Python 3
                izip = zip
                imap = map


                digits = 4
                variables = 10
                times_until = 500
                maxtries = 25
                times_done = 0
                average_cal = 0

                fmt = '%0' + str(digits) + 'd'
                searchspace = tuple([tuple(map(int,fmt % i)) for i in range(0,variables**digits)])

                def compare(a, b, imap=imap, sum=sum, izip=izip, min=min):
                count1 = [0] * variables
                count2 = [0] * variables
                        strikes = 0
                for dig1, dig2 in izip(a,b):
                if dig1 == dig2:
                strikes += 1
                count1[dig1] += 1
                count2[dig2] += 1
                balls = sum(imap(min, count1, count2)) - strikes
                return (strikes, balls)

                def restart_game():
                hidden_code = random.choice(searchspace)
                rungame(hidden_code, strategy_allrand)

                def rungame(target, strategy, verbose=True):#, maxtries=):
                possibles = list(searchspace)
                for i in range(maxtries):
                g = strategy(i, possibles)
                #if verbose:
                #print ("Out of %7d possibilities.  I'll guess %r" % (len(possibles), g),)
                score = compare(g, target)
                #if verbose:
                #print (' ---> ', score)
                if score[0] == digits:
                if verbose:
                print ("That's it.  After %d tries, I won." % (i+1,))
                global times_done
                times_done += 1

                global average_cal
                average_cal += (i+1)

                if times_done <= times_until:
                restart_game()
                else:
                print ("That's it. Average %f " % (average_cal/times_until,))
                break
                        possibles = [n for n in possibles if compare(g, n) == score]
                return i+1

                def strategy_allrand(i, possibles):
                return random.choice(possibles)



                if __name__ == '__main__':
                hidden_code = random.choice(searchspace)
                rungame(hidden_code, strategy_allrand)
```

Comment: Format your source code. In its current form it is very hard to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it from your code, you call function rungame from function restart_game, and if

```
if times_done <= times_until:
```

you call restart_game from rungame. Therefore, if times_until variable exceed certain value you get maximum recursion depth exceeded error.
You get a sequence of nested calls of the form

```
rungame(...)
restart_game(...)
rungame(...)
restart_game(...)
...
```

To increase the maximum recursion depth you could use sys.setrecursionlimit function. But a far better solution would be to rewrite your code in such a way
to get rid of recursion.

Comment: Sorry I was still trying to format the code, i'm new to stackoverflow too :p
and thank you, I'll look up to sys.setrecursionlimit function, since I don't think that i can rewrite it in a better way.